# Por que me salta el error en el foreach en php?

Tags: php, foreach

Tengo un problema a la hora de realizar el foreach el cual me marca un error Expected type 'iterable|object'. Found 'string|false', no entiendo por qué si en el tutorial que sigo la persona lo ejecuta correctamente.

```
<?php

$jsonContenido = '[{"Nombre":"Oscar", "apellido":"uh" },
{"nombre": "Brayan","apellido":"cabrera"} ]';

$resultado = json_encode($jsonContenido);

foreach ($resultado as $persona) {
    echo ($persona-> nombre)." ".($persona-> apellido)."<br/>";
}

?>
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a SOes!. Vendría mejor que especifiques más tu pregunta mostrando tu código completo y también lo que estás intentado resolver a más detalle, recuerda adjuntar el código en su respectivo formato. Te invito a que visites el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y mires [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) dándonos un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, ¡Saludos!.

Comment: Tienes un error tipográfico en **"Nombre"**, donde lo has puesto en mayúsculas dentro del **$jsonContenido** pero luego lo buscas en minúsculas cuando lo pones así: `$persona->nombre`.  Aparte de eso, cambia el **json_encode** por **json_decode** para convertir eso en un array de objetos que luego puedas recorrer con el foreach sin errores.

Comment: Creo que te haz equivocado de función, sería decode para descrifar el json y pasarlo a nativo de php. encode lo que hace es pasar convertirlo a json

Answer (score 3):

Estás haciendo *encode* cuando debería ser un *decode*. Estás intentando decodificar un JSON ya construido cuando lo que quieres es codificarlo en un array, es decir de JSON a array. Si quisieras hacerlo al revés, de array a JSON, sí que tendrías que hacer encode.
Además, en el primer elemento pones *Nombre* con la N mayúscula. El código correcto sería este:

```
<?php

$jsonContenido = '[{"nombre":"Oscar", "apellido":"uh" },
{"nombre":"Brayan", "apellido":"cabrera"}]';

$resultado = json_decode($jsonContenido);

foreach ($resultado as $persona) {
    echo ($persona->nombre)." ".($persona->apellido)."<br/>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias